# .scrollTarget() modifier not found in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

I'm implementing paginated scroll in `SwiftUI`, according to some articles such as:

https://farhanadji.medium.com/exploring-swiftui-scrollview-updates-from-wwdc-2023-2c69c7a813cc

https://swiftwithmajid.com/2023/06/20/mastering-scrollview-in-swiftui-target-behavior/

there's a `scrollTarget` modifier to make the scroll snap based on the individual items, instead of the whole container (which is done using the `scrollTargetLayout` modifier). However, `scrollTarget` seems not defined as I'm getting the next compilation error:

```
Value of type 'some View' has no member 'scrollTarget'
```

Am I missing something obvious? Maybe this modifier was removed from the api?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(0..<100) { number in
                Text(verbatim: String(number))
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 300)
                    .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.green))
                    .scrollTarget()
            }
        }
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give more context? maybe some piece of your actual code?

Comment: From what I can read in documentation, ScrollTarget `A type defining the target in which a scroll view should try and scroll to.`but is a public struct so Maybe is a custom modifier this guy have and forgot to add in the article

Comment: Well I'm doing pretty much the same that what's described in the articles but updating my question for clarity's sake. It might be a custom modifier indeed but it just seemed weird that two different authors shared the same.